# Running tcsh scripts on startup in bash env

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a user called `foo` which is using `tcsh` by default in `/etc/passwd`. I cannot change that default shell. Foo has a service called `xyz` running, for which all the startup scripts and .(dot) file containing ENV variables are in home dir of foo.

Now a startup script is also created to run that service and placed in `/etc/init.d/xyz` which is written in bash.

Now the issue is that the service is not starting on boot and I cannot run it from my default user on login too. It is only possible to run when I su into foo user and execute the script to start the service.

If I do like this

`sudo su foo /home/foo/xyz` it will show me errors like `then: then/endif not found.`.

So what I want to run a tcsh program to run on boot from a init.d script which is in bash. At present I tried to do this

`su - foo -c "source /home/foo/.env_vars && /home/foo/bin/xyz start"` but this is not starting the service at the time of boot.

I am not sure how to make a tcsh script execute on boot time.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo -u foo tcsh /home/foo/script` ?

Comment: Pretty much what @jonathanjo says, just use tcsh on the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- use `tcsh -c $script` to run the scripts with tcsh
- set the shebang (first line) in the script to `#!/bin/tcsh` and set it executable; you can then just start it with `$script` as the command.